# Spring annotations : form validation of a bean internal object attribute using thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-boot, thymeleaf

is there a way in Thymeleaf to validate an attribute in object property of a bean?
Consider that we do have a Departement class as below :

```
public class Departement {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long idDept;

   @NotEmpty
   private String name;
}
```

And another Employee class as follow

```
public class Employee{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long idEmp;

  @NotEmpty
  @Size(min = 5, message="At least five characters needed")
  private String employeeName;

  @NotNull
  private Departement departement;
}
```

With the code above using thymeleaf in the employee form only 'employeeName' will be validated by spring because of annotations.
Let's take a look here
In my controller

```
@GetMapping( value = "/emp" )
public String save(Model model){
  Employee emp = new Employee();
  emp.setDepartement(new Departement());
  model.addAttribute('employee', emp);
  return 'view';
}
//------------- Form in PostMapping
@PostMapping( value = "/save", @Valid Emp emp, BindingResult bindingResult )
public String savePost(Model model){
if( ! bindingResult.hasErrors() )
    {
 /* Even if departement has not been choosen, my code always goes here 
and print "Form Ok. Departement : 0" instead of reaching the 'else' block, but if departement choosen, 
it prints the correct value of departemnt 
*/
      System.out.println( "Form Ok.\n Departement : " + emp.getDepartement().getIdDept() );
  }else{
           System.out.println( "Missing attributes." );
  }

  return 'view';
}
```

And here goes the employee form

```
 <form th:action="@{save}" th:object="${emp}" th:method="POST" >
  <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('employeeName') }"th:errors="*{employeeName}"></span>
    <input th:field="*{employeeName}" th:value="${employeeName}" />
//--------
   <div th:object="${emp.departement}">
      <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('idDept') }"th:errors="*{idDept}"></span>
      <input th:field="*{idDept}" th:value="${idDept}" />
   </div>
</form>
```

**Here is my question :
How can I validate the employee departement identifier (idDept field) without using javacript in the emplpoyee form? 
**

*NB : I don't use drowpdownlist for displaying departements but prefer an autocomplete field and a hidden field that take the choosen departement id.*

Comment: Put `@Valid` on the nested object, as needed by JSR303 to validate nested objects.

Comment: As @M.Deinum mentioned put `@Valid` inside `public String fct(@Valid Employee employee, BindingResult result, Model model ){ //your code here}`. Can you write a meaningful name for the method name fct and in your form `form th:action="@{save}"` will not request any where better make it `form th:action="@{/save}"` and put the same path in controller.

Comment: Code was edited. Thank you for your answers. I've just forgot to put the @PostMapping code here, otherwise I had already used '@Valid' annotation in my Post. 
Please try to read the PostMapping code with the comment and tell me what you think about it. Personnally I just think that the '@NotNull' just test if Departement is not null and don't go inside for verifying if Id field value is different from zero (0).

Comment: I wasn't mentioning the `@Valid` on the mapping I was suggesting the `@Valid` on the embedded object (as I imho clearly stated in the comment).

Comment: Ok @M. Deinum, I've just figured it out. Thank you, it's the same idea suggested by @@Stefan Haberl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSR-303 mandates the use of a `@Valid` annotation to recursively validate nested components as mentioned in the [Hibernate Validator docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-builtin-constraints).

So just put `@Valid` on your nested components, in your case on the department field within the employee class:

```
public class Employee {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long idEmp;

  @NotEmpty
  @Size(min = 5, message="At least five characters needed")
  private String employeeName;

  @NotNull
  @Valid 
  private Departement departement;
}
```

Comment: Code was edited. Thank you for your answers. I've just forgot to put the @PostMapping code here, otherwise I had already used '@Valid' annotation in my Post. Please try to read the PostMapping (in the code edited or in my next answer) with the comment and tell me what you think about it. Personnally I just think that the '@NotNull' just test if Departement is not null and don't go inside for verifying if Id field value is different from zero (0).

Comment: Yep, you're guessing right. try my answer. Should work

Comment: Right, I'll be back after testing.

Comment: It does work fine guy. Thank you, I wasted a lot of time looking for this. Pfff!

Comment: No problem. Please upvote my answer, if it was of any help to you. Since you are using Spring MVC I guess you are using Hibernate Validator as your JSR-303 validation provider. I recommend reading the relevant docs at https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-builtin-constraints

Comment: Ok I'll do I'll do it as soon as possible. Thank you. Sorry for the other request but I don't have enough reputation for submitting votes.

Comment: I do not know if you're still there, but I've tried to use `@Valid` and in the form, once the employee department has been chosen, the validation remains wrong because it asks All constraints of the nested object are validated